# woo commerce get_subtotal( ) doesn't get any value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to format the order emails in woocommerce/wp. Unfortunately the function [get_subtotal()](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_subtotal) doesn't work.

```
 $TT = $order->get_subtotal();
```

The strange thing is, the every other functions on the same class is working find f.e. `$tax = $oder->get_taxes();`

I tried to google what's wrong, but couldn't find anything. On the above list there is mentioned that this is "public mixed" What does this mean?

Comment: Just a quick one, I believe that you may be better off with get_subtotal_to_display() from the same class? Have you tried that?

Comment: display more code please :)

Comment: @daniel, thanks, this works, but the output doesn't seem to be an integer value - because if i try to if($tt>=100) it do not work. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Are you changing the value or just checking it? This gets the html to display the subtotal, if you want to change that then use the filter instead (woocommerce_order_subtotal_to_display)

Comment: Thanks. i just want to give out some additional information if the subtotal its over $100. can you help me how to use this filter (i'm sorry, I'm really on the beginning to understand woocommers….)

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? What is the result of `$TT` and what were you expecting?